# Integral $ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{7+6\cos(x)-2\sin(x)}dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

So I just had an exam and one of the exercises was this integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{7+6\cos(x)-2\sin(x)}dx $$

My first thought was the the substitution $u=\tan(x/2)$.So I found $\sin x, \cos x$ and $dx$ and I replaced in my integral.Then I remembered that teacher said something that this substitution does not work in some cases. He said something about the range. So I give up on this method, then I split the integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ to $pi$. Now the first integral I tried to solve again with $u=\tan(x/2)$ and at the second one I got stuck.

Another method I tried is with King property: $f(a+b-x)=f(x)$ but I got nothing.

Other substitution I tried is $x=\pi-t$ but I also got stuck on this.

So my question is how to solve this integral?

I solved this kind of integral and the solving process was more "elegant".Like I apply $x=\pi-x$ then I write the integral in 2 different ways.Then I find the sum of them....and on and on.

Comment: Here, Bioche's rules say you indeed should use the substitution $t=\tan\frac x2$, $dx=\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: what is king property .it isn't written in my textbook by 'king' name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\tan\frac x2$ is continuous on $(0,\pi)$, so no need to split up the integral as you mention.

$$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x}{7+6\cos x-2\sin x}\,\mathrm dx$$

With $u=\tan\frac x2$, we get $\mathrm du=\frac12\sec^2\frac x2\,\mathrm dx$ and

$$\sin x=2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\\
\cos x=\cos^2\frac x2-\sin^2\frac x2=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

Then

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac{2u}{1+u^2}}{7+\frac{6(1-u^2)}{1+u^2}-\frac{4u}{1+u^2}}\frac{2\,\mathrm du}{1+u^2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{4u}{(1+u^2)(13-4u+u^2)}\,\mathrm du$$

Comment: Yes, I got your result and then I tried another method.Thank you

Comment: There's an error in the denominator.

Comment: Sure about that? The rational function that I got was$$\frac{2-2u^2}{\left(u^2+1\right) \left(9 u^2+12 u+5\right)}.$$

Comment: I don't even remember but I'm pretty sure that I got the correct rational function.I used half angle formula, I got a rational function then I tried another method.Anyway, it's easy from here to solve it.Thanks again

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I do that quite often ... Fixed

Comment: As the denominator can be factored, this can be solved explicitly but you are not quite there yet. You have just transformed one integral which can be solved in general into another one that can be solved in general.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm not sure how you arrived at that, that seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @user170231 Yes, I made a mistake. Sorry for wasting your time.